# Eliminar item de RecyclerView en kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, kotlin, android-fragment

Error al momento de eliminar item de moviesList, propiedad moviesList no esta inicializada en `MovieAdapter()`,  a mi entender, la estoy inicializando en el constructor secundario, muchas gracias por su ayuda.

En el *movieFragment* hice lo siguiente:

```
override fun onMovieClick(movie: Movie, position: Int) {
        val action = MovieFragmentDirections.actionMovieFragmentToMovieDetailFragment(
            movie.poster_path,
            movie.backdrop_path,
            movie.vote_average.toFloat(),
            movie.vote_count,
            movie.overview,
            movie.title,
            movie.original_language,
            movie.release_date
        )
 
        MovieAdapter().removedItemMovied(position)  // *******AQUI LLAMO AL METODO ELIMINAR DEL ADAPTER
        binding.rvMovies.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
        binding.rvMovies.scrollToPosition(0)
 
        //findNavController().navigate(action)
    }
```

Y en `class MovieAdapter()`, declaro un método que haga lo siguiente:

```
class MovieAdapter() : RecyclerView.Adapter<BaseViewHolder<*>>() {
 
    private var cardList: MutableList<Card> = mutableListOf()
    private lateinit var itemClickListener: onCardClickListener
 
    constructor(moviesList: MutableList<Movie>, itemClickListener: OnMovieClickLi  stener): this(){
        this.moviesList = moviesList
        this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener

        Log.i("adapter", "cantidad elementos ${moviesList.size}")
    }
 
 
   //metodo que llamo desde MovieFragment, tira error
   fun removedItemMovied(position: Int){
        this.moviesList.removeAt(position)
        notifyItemRemoved(position)
        Log.i("adapter", "cantidad elementos ${moviesList.size}")
    }
}
```

Tengo el siguiente error:

> kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property moviesList has not been initialized
> at com.example.movieapp.ui.movie.adapters.MovieAdapter.removedItemMovied(MovieAdapter.kt:51)
> at com.example.movieapp.ui.movie.MovieFragment.onMovieClick(MovieFragment.kt:104)
> at com.example.movieapp.ui.movie.adapters.MovieAdapter$onCreateViewHolder$1.onClick(MovieAdapter.kt:37)

Answer (score 1):

En tu Adapter, estás inicializando una propiedad cardList pero estas pasando al constructor una propiedad moviesList e intentando asignarla a una propiedad que no has inicializado.

Prueba inicializando moviesList

```
class MovieAdapter() : RecyclerView.Adapter<BaseViewHolder<*>>() {
 
    private var cardList: MutableList<Card> = mutableListOf()
    private var moviesList: MutableList<Movies> = mutableListOf()
    private lateinit var itemClickListener: onCardClickListener
 
    constructor(moviesList: MutableList<Movie>, 
                itemClickListener: OnMovieClickLi  stener): this(){
        this.moviesList = moviesList
        this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener
    }
 
 
   //metodo que llamo desde MovieFragment, tira error
   fun removedItemMovied(position: Int){
        this.moviesList.removeAt(position)
        notifyItemRemoved(position)
        Log.i("adapter", "cantidad elementos ${moviesList.size}")
    }
 
}
```

Comment: Gracias, Raul, en vez de cardList debe ir moviesList. Ya inizialize como tu planteas, pero la cantidad de elementos en la lista moviesList es igual a cero, al momento de llamar la funcion removedItemMovied(), del adaptador.  Tengo una duda en la forma como estoy definiendo las propiedades en los constructores, pero no se como mas hacerlo.

Answer (score 0):

La clase MovieAdapter() tiene dos constructores, lo que experimente es que la instanciar el constructor vacio,  MovieAdapter().removedItemMovied(position), en la funcion removedItemMovied(), no se puede acceder a las valores de las propiedades del constructor con parametros: osea la lista moviesList, siempre esta vacia.

Para solucionarlo hice lo siguiente:

Inicializar en el constructor primario-header, las propiedades, con el fin de poder crear una instancia en el fragmentMovie

```
MovieAdapter(private var moviesList: MutableList<Movie> = mutableListOf(),
               private var itemClickListener: OnMovieClickListener? = null):
    RecyclerView.Adapter<BaseViewHolder<*>>() {
    

   fun cantidadAdapter(card: Card, position: Int) {
        Log.i("adapter", "cantidad_item: ${cardList.size}")
        cardList.removeAt(position)
        cardList.add(0, card)

        notifyItemMoved(position, 0)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    
}
```

MovieFragment()

```
    class MovieFragment : Fragment(R.layout.fragment_movie), MovieAdapter.OnMovieClickListener {
    
          private var movieAdapter: MovieAdapter = MovieAdapter()
        
         override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
                super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
                binding = FragmentMovieBinding.bind(view){
          
        
    viewModel.fetchMainScreenMovies().observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { result ->
                when (result) {
                    
                    is Resource.Success -> {
                        Log.d("TestLog", "onViewCreated: ")
                        binding.progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
    
                        movieAdapter = MovieAdapter(result.data.first.results, this@MovieFragment)
                        concatAdapter.apply {
                            addAdapter(0, UpcomingConcatAdapter(movieAdapter))
                        }
    
                        binding.rvMovies.adapter = concatAdapter
                    }
                    
                }
            })
    
      }

override fun onMovieClick(movie: Movie, position: Int) {
        val action = MovieFragmentDirections.actionMovieFragmentToMovieDetailFragment(
            movie.poster_path,
            movie.backdrop_path,
            movie.vote_average.toFloat(),
            movie.vote_count,
            movie.overview,
            movie.title,
            movie.original_language,
            movie.release_date
        )

        //AQUI LLAMO A LA FUNCIO ELIMINAR DE LA CLASE ADAPTADOR
        movieAdapter.removedItemMovied(position)
        //binding.rvMovies.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
        binding.rvMovies.scrollToPosition(0)

        //findNavController().navigate(action)
    }


}
```